# Calling the value of a variable inside for loop when writing to a text file

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, file-writing

I want to create a text file from python whereby I want the value of a variable to change iteratively inside the for loop. However, I am unable to call the value of the variable inside the loop. Instead it just prints the the variable as string. The code is as follow:

```
f = open('workfile.txt, 'w')
for i in range (1,152):
a = 1
f.write('BEGIN PERIOD a \n')
f.write('6 1 1200.0 90.0 \n')
f.write('END PERIOD a \n')
a +=1
f.close()
```

Here, after the BEGIN PERIOD and END PERIOD inside the f.write function, I want the value of ''**a**'' to change every time the loop runs. However, the program prints ''**a**'' as a string. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `'BEGIN PERIOD a \n'` is a string. Program cannot recognize that you want to print value of `a`. What you need to do is to divide your string and specify you variable to get its value: `'BEGIN PERIOD ' + str(a) + '\n'`.

But there is one problem, you run `a = 1` on each iteration, therefore it does not matter you increase the value or not here `a +=1`, your code will print `a` always as `1`.

Better not to use `a` because you already have an iterator `i`. You can use below code:

```
f = open('workfile.txt', 'w')
for i in range(1, 152):
    f.write('BEGIN PERIOD ' + str(i) + '\n')
    f.write('6 1 1200.0 90.0 \n')
    f.write('END PERIOD ' + str(i) + '\n')
f.close()
```

`for i in range(1, 152):` here for loop iterates variable `i` starting from 1 (inclusive) to 152 (exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `a` outside the loop:

```py
a = 1

for i in range(1, 152):
    ...
    a += 1
```

If it is declared inside the loop, every time the loop loops again, there will be a new `a`. If you want to keep it always online, you need to decalre it outside the loop scope.

And if you want to use `a`, you can try `format`:

```py
a = 1

for i in range(1, 152):
    ...
    a += 1
    print('a is {}'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems.
(i) Initialization of a should be outside the loop
(ii) in f.write() it should be %d formatting and supply the variable name

Working code as below:

```
f = open('workfile.txt', 'w')
a = 1
for i in range (1,152):
    f.write('BEGIN PERIOD %d \n' %(a))
    f.write('6 1 1200.0 90.0 \n')
    f.write('END PERIOD %d \n' %(a))
    a +=1
f.close()
```